# Lightweight asynchronous event library in C - Threadpool module

Tags: c, multithreading, asynchronous, library, pthreads

I have finished writing a C library whose purpose is to provide a simple API for asynchronously executing functions, waiting for events on file descriptors and waiting for timeouts. The whole library is published here https://github.com/ernacktob/asyncio. The entire library is probably too large to be reviewed in a single question, so I am trying to split things up into the separate modules.

In this question I am interested in feedback for the threadpool module. The purpose of this module is to implement an API for submitting functions to be executed by a fixed pool of worker threads, or optionally, spawn a separate thread just for this function.

The overall structure of this module consists of a global queue of tasks to be executed by a fixed set of worker threads, and another global queue for "contractor" threads (which are threads spawned for an individual task). The user calls threadpool_dispatch to submit a function to the thread pool, and a structure containing all the relevant information is stored in the appropriate queue. The worker threads wait on the queue, and the first to wake will take the first task from the queue and execute it. The purpose of contractor threads is to handle cases where the task might take a long time to complete, and would stall the worker queue. So this provides the user the option to spawn a dedicated thread for that task, bypassing the worker queue. The module uses the underlying POSIX pthread library for actually creating/cancelling threads, as well as mutex and condition variables.

The API provides a threadpool_handle_t, which is an opaque pointer to a threadpool_handle struct. This handle is used for the user to do things such as blocking until the task is completed (threadpool_join) or cancelling the task (threadpool_cancel).

The public interface to this module is the following (taken from the include/threadpool.h header). The public functions are all defined at the bottom of the source file, with the rest being internal to this module.

```
#ifndef THREADPOOL_H
#define THREADPOOL_H

#include <stdint.h>

#define THREADPOOL_FLAG_NONE        0
#define THREADPOOL_FLAG_CONTRACTOR  (1 << 0)
#define THREADPOOL_FLAG_CANCELLABLE (1 << 1)
#define THREADPOOL_FLAG_ASYNCCANCEL (1 << 2)

typedef void *threadpool_handle_t;

typedef void (*threadpool_function)(void *arg);
typedef void (*threadpool_callback)(void *arg);

struct threadpool_function_info {
    threadpool_function fn;
    void *arg;
};

struct threadpool_callback_info {
    threadpool_callback cb;
    void *arg;
};

struct threadpool_dispatch_info {
    uint32_t flags;
    struct threadpool_function_info dispatch_info;          /* Function to be executed asynchronously by the thread pool. Cannot be NULL. */
    struct threadpool_callback_info completed_info;         /* Function to be called after dispatch_func has completed. Ignored if NULL. */
    struct threadpool_callback_info cancelled_info;         /* Function to be called after dispatch_func has been cancelled. Ignored if NULL. */
};

int threadpool_dispatch(struct threadpool_dispatch_info *task, threadpool_handle_t *handlep);
int threadpool_cancel(threadpool_handle_t handle);
int threadpool_join(threadpool_handle_t handle);
int threadpool_acquire_handle(threadpool_handle_t handle);
void threadpool_release_handle(threadpool_handle_t handle);

#endif
```

I would specifically be interested in knowing whether there are any issues with race conditions, deadlocks or performance (in terms of ressource usage or speed), but any other criticism will be appreciated as well. Note that some functions or macros are defined in other modules or header files, but they are available in the full project link above.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <sys/errno.h>

#include "threadpool.h"
#include "cancellations.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "safe_malloc.h"
#include "logging.h"

#define MAX_WORKER_THREADS      5
#define MAX_CONTRACTORS         1024

#define UINT64T_MAX         ((uint64_t)(-1)) /* Get rid of compiler warning about 'use of C99 long long integer constant' for UINT64_MAX */

/* STRUCT DEFINITIONS */
struct threadpool_handle {
    pthread_mutex_t mtx;
    uint64_t refcount;  /* Protected by mtx */

    struct threadpool_dispatch_info info;
    pthread_t thread;
    struct worker_thread_info *worker_info; /* If NULL, handled by contractor instead of worker. Protected by worker_threads_mtx */
    int in_worker_queue;    /* used to know if worker has it in its task queue. Protected by worker_threads_mtx */

    int in_contractor_queue;    /* Used to know if in contractor queue. Protected by contractors_mtx */

    pthread_mutex_t finished_cond_mtx;
    pthread_cond_t finished_cond;
    int finished;       /* Protected by finished_cond_mtx */

    /* Used for task queues */
    struct threadpool_handle *prev;
    struct threadpool_handle *next;
};

struct worker_thread_info {
    int initialized;                    /* Protected by worker_threads_mtx */
    int running;                        /* Protected by worker_threads_mtx */
    pthread_t thread;
};
/* END STRUCT DEFINITIONS */

/* PROTOTYPES */
static void unlock_finished_cond_mtx(void *arg);

static void notify_handle_finished(struct threadpool_handle *handle);

static void contractor_finished(void);
static void contractor_cleanup(void *arg);
static void *contractor_thread(void *arg);

static void worker_handle_cleanup(void *arg);
static void worker_cleanup(void *arg);
static void *worker_thread(void *arg);

static int push_worker_task_locked(struct threadpool_handle *handle);
static int pull_worker_task(struct worker_thread_info *worker_info, struct threadpool_handle **handlep);

static int dispatch_contractor(struct threadpool_handle *handle);
static int dispatch_worker(struct threadpool_handle *handle);

static int init_threadpool_handle(struct threadpool_handle *handle, struct threadpool_dispatch_info *task);
static void cleanup_threadpool_handle(struct threadpool_handle *handle);

static void init_worker_info(struct worker_thread_info *info);
/* END PROTOTYPES */

/* GLOBALS */
pthread_mutex_t worker_threads_mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static struct worker_thread_info worker_threads[MAX_WORKER_THREADS];    /* Protected by worker_threads_mtx */
pthread_cond_t workers_newtask_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;     /* Protected by worker_threads_mtx */
decl_queue(struct threadpool_handle, workers_task_queue);       /* Protected by worker_threads_mtx */
static int workers_initialized = 0;                 /* Protected by worker_threads_mtx */

pthread_mutex_t contractors_mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
uint64_t contractors_count = 0;                     /* Protected by contractors_mtx */
decl_queue(struct threadpool_handle, contractors_task_queue);       /* Protected by contractors_mtx */
static int contractors_initialized = 0;                 /* Protected by contractors_mtx */
/* END GLOBALS */

static void unlock_finished_cond_mtx(void *arg)
{
    struct threadpool_handle *handle;
    int rc;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", arg));

    handle = (struct threadpool_handle *)arg;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &handle->finished_cond_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&handle->finished_cond_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
}

static void notify_handle_finished(struct threadpool_handle *handle)
{
    int rc;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", handle));

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_lock) ARG("%p", &handle->finished_cond_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&handle->finished_cond_mtx)) == 0) {
        handle->finished = 1;

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_cond_broadcast) ARG("%p", &handle->finished_cond));
        if ((rc = pthread_cond_broadcast(&handle->finished_cond)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_cond_broadcast");
        }

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &handle->finished_cond_mtx));
        if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&handle->finished_cond_mtx)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
        }
    } else {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_lock");
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
}

static void contractor_finished(void)
{
    struct threadpool_handle *handle;
    pthread_t thread;
    int rc;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_lock) ARG("%p", &contractors_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&contractors_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_lock");
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
        return;
    }

    if (contractors_count == 0) {
        ASYNCIO_ERROR("contractor count already 0.\n");

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &contractors_mtx));
        if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&contractors_mtx)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
        }

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
        return;
    }

    --contractors_count;

    /* Dispatch new contractor for tasks in contractors task queue */
    if (!queue_empty(&contractors_task_queue)) {
        queue_pop(&contractors_task_queue, &handle);

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(5 FUNC(pthread_create) ARG("%p", &thread) ARG("%p", NULL) ARG("%p", contractor_thread) ARG("%p", handle));
        if ((rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, contractor_thread, handle)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_create");

            queue_push(&contractors_task_queue, handle);    /* XXX Should push back to where it was? */

            ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &contractors_mtx));
            if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&contractors_mtx)) != 0) {
                errno = rc;
                ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
            }

            ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
            return;
        }

        handle->thread = thread;
        handle->in_contractor_queue = 0;
        ++contractors_count;
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &contractors_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&contractors_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
}

static void contractor_cleanup(void *arg)
{
    struct threadpool_handle *handle;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", arg));

    /* handle was acquired in contractor_thread */
    handle = (struct threadpool_handle *)arg;

    notify_handle_finished(handle);

    /* Call cancelled callback */
    if (handle->info.cancelled_info.cb != NULL)
        handle->info.cancelled_info.cb(handle->info.cancelled_info.arg);

    /* Release our handle */
    threadpool_release_handle(handle);

    contractor_finished();

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
}

static void *contractor_thread(void *arg)
{
    struct threadpool_handle *handle;
    int oldstate, oldstate1;
    int oldtype;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", arg));
    disable_cancellations(&oldstate);

    handle = (struct threadpool_handle *)arg;
    pthread_cleanup_push(contractor_cleanup, handle);

    if (handle->info.flags & THREADPOOL_FLAG_ASYNCCANCEL)
        set_canceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, &oldtype);
    else
        set_canceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, &oldtype);

    if (handle->info.flags & THREADPOOL_FLAG_CANCELLABLE)
        set_cancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, &oldstate1);
    else
        set_cancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, &oldstate1);

    /* Execute the dispatched function */
    handle->info.dispatch_info.fn(handle->info.dispatch_info.arg);

    disable_cancellations(&oldstate1);
    restore_canceltype(oldtype);

    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);

    /* Broadcast condition that thread finished */
    notify_handle_finished(handle);

    /* Call completed callback */
    if (handle->info.completed_info.cb != NULL)
        handle->info.completed_info.cb(handle->info.completed_info.arg);

    threadpool_release_handle(handle); /* It was acquired implicitly by threadpool_dispatch when it dispatched it to us */

    contractor_finished();

    restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%p", NULL));
    return NULL;
}

static void worker_handle_cleanup(void *arg)
{
    struct threadpool_handle *handle;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", arg));

    /* handle was acquired in contractor_thread */
    handle = (struct threadpool_handle *)arg;

    notify_handle_finished(handle);

    /* Call cancelled callback */
    if (handle->info.cancelled_info.cb != NULL)
        handle->info.cancelled_info.cb(handle->info.cancelled_info.arg);

    /* Release our handle */
    threadpool_release_handle(handle);

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
}

static void worker_cleanup(void *arg)
{
    struct worker_thread_info *worker_info;
    pthread_t thread;
    int rc;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", arg));

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_lock) ARG("%p", &worker_threads_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&worker_threads_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_lock");
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
        return;
    }

    worker_info = (struct worker_thread_info *)arg;
    worker_info->running = 0;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(5 FUNC(pthread_create) ARG("%p", &thread) ARG("%p", NULL) ARG("%p", worker_thread) ARG("%p", worker_info));
    if ((rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, worker_thread, worker_info)) == 0) {
        worker_info->running = 1;
        worker_info->thread = thread;
    } else {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_create\n");
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &worker_threads_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&worker_threads_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
}

static void *worker_thread(void *arg)
{
    struct worker_thread_info *worker_info;
    struct threadpool_handle *handle;
    int oldstate, oldstate1;
    int oldtype;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", arg));
    disable_cancellations(&oldstate);

    worker_info = (struct worker_thread_info *)arg;

    pthread_cleanup_push(worker_cleanup, worker_info);

    for (;;) {
        if (pull_worker_task(worker_info, &handle) != 0) {
            ASYNCIO_ERROR("Failed to pull worker task.\n");
            ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(usleep) ARG("%d", 10000));
            usleep(10000);
            continue;
        }

        pthread_cleanup_push(worker_handle_cleanup, handle);

        if (handle->info.flags & THREADPOOL_FLAG_ASYNCCANCEL)
            set_canceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, &oldtype);
        else
            set_canceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, &oldtype);

        if (handle->info.flags & THREADPOOL_FLAG_CANCELLABLE)
            set_cancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, &oldstate1);
        else
            set_cancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, &oldstate1);

        /* Execute dispatched function */
        handle->info.dispatch_info.fn(handle->info.dispatch_info.arg);

        disable_cancellations(&oldstate1);
        restore_canceltype(oldtype);

        pthread_cleanup_pop(0);

        /* Broadcast condition that thread finished */
        notify_handle_finished(handle);

        /* Call completed callback */
        if (handle->info.completed_info.cb != NULL)
            handle->info.completed_info.cb(handle->info.completed_info.arg);

        threadpool_release_handle(handle);
    }

    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
    worker_info->running = 0;

    restore_cancelstate(oldstate);

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%p", NULL));
    return NULL;
}

static int push_worker_task_locked(struct threadpool_handle *handle)
{
    int rc;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", handle));

    /* Push new task into worker task queue */
    queue_push(&workers_task_queue, handle);

    /* Wake up a worker */
    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_cond_signal) ARG("%p", &workers_newtask_cond));
    if ((rc = pthread_cond_signal(&workers_newtask_cond)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_cond_signal\n");

        queue_remove(&workers_task_queue, handle);
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    handle->in_worker_queue = 1;
    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", 0));
    return 0;
}

static int pull_worker_task(struct worker_thread_info *worker_info, struct threadpool_handle **handlep)
{
    struct threadpool_handle *handle;
    int rc;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(2 ARG("%p", worker_info) ARG("%p", handlep));

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_lock) ARG("%p", &worker_threads_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&worker_threads_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_lock");
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    while (queue_empty(&workers_task_queue)) {
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(3 FUNC(pthread_cond_wait) ARG("%p", &workers_newtask_cond) ARG("%p", &worker_threads_mtx));
        if ((rc = pthread_cond_wait(&workers_newtask_cond, &worker_threads_mtx)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_cond_wait");

            ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &worker_threads_mtx));
            if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&worker_threads_mtx)) != 0) {
                errno = rc;
                ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
            }

            ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /* Pop new task from queue (this is a misnomer... it's not pop-ing the task that was pushed like a stack) */
    queue_pop(&workers_task_queue, &handle);
    handle->thread = worker_info->thread;
    handle->worker_info = worker_info;
    handle->in_worker_queue = 0; /* Protected by the worker_threads_mtx */

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &worker_threads_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&worker_threads_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
        /* Return anyways since we already got the handle anyways... */
    }

    *handlep = handle;
    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", 0));
    return 0;
}

static int init_threadpool_handle(struct threadpool_handle *handle, struct threadpool_dispatch_info *task)
{
    int rc;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(2 ARG("%p", handle) ARG("%p", task));
    handle->info = *task;
    handle->refcount = 0;
    handle->finished = 0;
    handle->worker_info = NULL;
    handle->in_worker_queue = 0;
    handle->in_contractor_queue = 0;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(3 FUNC(pthread_mutex_init) ARG("%p", &handle->mtx) ARG("%p", NULL));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_init(&handle->mtx, NULL)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_init");
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(3 FUNC(pthread_mutex_init) ARG("%p", &handle->finished_cond_mtx) ARG("%p", NULL));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_init(&handle->finished_cond_mtx, NULL)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_init");

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_destroy) ARG("%p", &handle->mtx));
        if ((rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(&handle->mtx)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_destroy");
        }

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(3 FUNC(pthread_cond_init) ARG("%p", &handle->finished_cond) ARG("%p", NULL));
    if ((rc = pthread_cond_init(&handle->finished_cond, NULL)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_cond_init");

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_destroy) ARG("%p", &handle->finished_cond_mtx));
        if ((rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(&handle->finished_cond_mtx)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_destroy");
        }

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_destroy) ARG("%p", &handle->mtx));
        if ((rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(&handle->mtx)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_destroy");
        }

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", 0));
    return 0;
}

static void cleanup_threadpool_handle(struct threadpool_handle *handle)
{
    int rc;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", handle));

    /* Should only detach if handle was with contractor. Worker threads are detached in worker cleanup. */
    if (handle->worker_info == NULL) {
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_detach) ARG("%016llx", handle->thread));
        if ((rc = pthread_detach(handle->thread)) != 0) {   /* Release pthread_t ressources for that thread (this is what allows multiple pthread_cancels()) */
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_detach");
        }
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_cond_destroy) ARG("%p", &handle->finished_cond));
    if ((rc = pthread_cond_destroy(&handle->finished_cond)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_cond_destroy");
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_destroy) ARG("%p", &handle->finished_cond_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(&handle->finished_cond_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_destroy");
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_destroy) ARG("%p", &handle->mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(&handle->mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_destroy");
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
}

static void init_worker_info(struct worker_thread_info *info)
{
    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", info));

    info->running = 0;
    info->initialized = 1;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);;
}

static int dispatch_contractor(struct threadpool_handle *handle)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int success;
    int rc;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", handle));

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_lock) ARG("%p", &contractors_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&contractors_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_lock");
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    if (!contractors_initialized) {
        queue_init(&contractors_task_queue);
        contractors_initialized = 1;
    }

    success = 1;

    if (contractors_count < MAX_CONTRACTORS) {
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(5 FUNC(pthread_create) ARG("%p", &thread) ARG("%p", NULL) ARG("%p", contractor_thread) ARG("%p", handle));
        if ((rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, contractor_thread, handle)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_create");
            success = 0;
        }

        handle->thread = thread;
        handle->in_contractor_queue = 0;
        ++contractors_count;
    } else {
        queue_push(&contractors_task_queue, handle);
        handle->in_contractor_queue = 1;
    }

    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&contractors_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
    }

    if (!success) {
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", 0));
    return 0;
}

static int dispatch_worker(struct threadpool_handle *handle)
{
    struct worker_thread_info *worker_info;
    pthread_t thread;
    size_t i;
    int rc;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", handle));

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_lock) ARG("%p", &worker_threads_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&worker_threads_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_lock");
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    if (!workers_initialized) {
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_WORKER_THREADS; i++)
            init_worker_info(&worker_threads[i]);

        queue_init(&workers_task_queue);
        workers_initialized = 1;
    }

    /* XXX Is this really necessary? Used in case pthread_create fails during worker cleanup,
     * so that we keep trying to respawn a worker after it got cancelled. */
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_WORKER_THREADS; i++) {
        worker_info = &worker_threads[i];

        /* Start worker thread if not running */
        if (!(worker_info->running)) {
            ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(5 FUNC(pthread_create) ARG("%p", &thread) ARG("%p", NULL) ARG("%p", worker_thread) ARG("%p", worker_info));
            if ((rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, worker_thread, worker_info)) != 0) {
                errno = rc;
                ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_create");
                continue;
            }

            worker_info->thread = thread;
            worker_info->running = 1;
        }
    }

    if (push_worker_task_locked(handle) != 0) {
        ASYNCIO_ERROR("Failed to push worker task.\n");

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &worker_threads_mtx));
        if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&worker_threads_mtx)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
        }

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &worker_threads_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&worker_threads_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", 0));
    return 0;
}

int threadpool_dispatch(struct threadpool_dispatch_info *task, threadpool_handle_t *handlep)
{
    struct threadpool_handle *handle;
    int oldstate;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(2 ARG("%p", task) ARG("%p", handlep));
    disable_cancellations(&oldstate);

    if (task->dispatch_info.fn == NULL) {
        restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    handle = safe_malloc(sizeof *handle);

    if (handle == NULL) {
        ASYNCIO_ERROR("safe_malloc");
        restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    if (init_threadpool_handle(handle, task) != 0) {
        safe_free(handle);

        restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    /* The caller must have a reference by default to prevent race conditions
     * where the task completes before the client had a chance to acquire the
     * handle. Also the contractor or worker thread must have a reference to
     * prevent the case where the client releases its handle before the worker
     * or contractor manages to acquire its handle */
    handle->refcount = 2;

    /* XXX Creating contractor threads seems to be much slower than dispatching to
     * the fixed number of worker threads, so only use them for tasks that are gonna
     * take a long time, to avoid slowing down batch-dispatching. */
    if (task->flags & THREADPOOL_FLAG_CONTRACTOR) {
        /* Give preference to contractor threads */
        if (dispatch_contractor(handle) == 0) {
            *handlep = (threadpool_handle_t)handle;
            restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
            ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", 0));
            return 0;
        }

        /* Try with worker thread instead */
        if (dispatch_worker(handle) == 0) {
            *handlep = (threadpool_handle_t)handle;
            restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
            ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", 0));
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        /* Give preference to worker threads */
        if (dispatch_worker(handle) == 0) {
            *handlep = (threadpool_handle_t)handle;
            restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
            ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", 0));
            return 0;
        }

        /* Try with contractor thread instead */
        if (dispatch_contractor(handle) == 0) {
            *handlep = (threadpool_handle_t)handle;
            restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
            ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", 0));
            return 0;
        }
    }

    cleanup_threadpool_handle(handle);

    safe_free(handle);

    restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
    return -1;
}

int threadpool_cancel(threadpool_handle_t thandle)
{
    struct threadpool_handle *handle;
    int oldstate;
    int rc;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", thandle));
    disable_cancellations(&oldstate);

    handle = (struct threadpool_handle *)thandle;

    /* Only cancel cancellable threads */
    if (!(handle->info.flags & THREADPOOL_FLAG_CANCELLABLE))
        return -1;

    /* Don't let thread cancel itself. */
    if (pthread_equal(handle->thread, pthread_self()))
        return -1;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_lock) ARG("%p", &worker_threads_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&worker_threads_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_lock");

        restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    /* Remove handle from worker queue (if in worker) */
    if (handle->worker_info != NULL) {
        if (handle->in_worker_queue) {
            queue_remove(&workers_task_queue, handle);
            handle->in_worker_queue = 0;
            notify_handle_finished(handle);
        } else {
            ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_cancel) ARG("%016llx", handle->thread));
            if ((rc = pthread_cancel(handle->thread)) != 0) {
                /* Some implementations return ESRCH if pthread_cancel is called
                 * on a thread that has already terminated normally by returning
                 * from the pthread_create callback function. This is not an error,
                 * just ignore it. */
                if (rc != ESRCH) {
                    errno = rc;
                    ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_cancel");

                    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &worker_threads_mtx));
                    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&worker_threads_mtx)) != 0) {
                        errno = rc;
                        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
                    }

                    restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
                    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &worker_threads_mtx));
        if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&worker_threads_mtx)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
        }

        restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", 0));
        return 0;
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &worker_threads_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&worker_threads_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_lock) ARG("%p", &contractors_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&contractors_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_lock");

        restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    if (handle->in_contractor_queue) {
        queue_remove(&contractors_task_queue, handle);
        notify_handle_finished(handle);
    } else {
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_cancel) ARG("%016llx", handle->thread));
        if ((rc = pthread_cancel(handle->thread)) != 0) {
            /* Some implementations return ESRCH if pthread_cancel is called
             * on a thread that has already terminated normally by returning
             * from the pthread_create callback function. This is not an error,
             * just ignore it. */
            if (rc != ESRCH) {
                errno = rc;
                ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_cancel");

                ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &contractors_mtx));
                if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&contractors_mtx)) != 0) {
                    errno = rc;
                    ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
                }

                restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
                ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &contractors_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&contractors_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
    }

    restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", 0));
    return 0;
}

int threadpool_join(threadpool_handle_t thandle)
{
    struct threadpool_handle *handle;
    int oldstate;
    int oldtype;
    int rc;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", thandle));
    disable_cancellations(&oldstate);

    handle = (struct threadpool_handle *)thandle;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_lock) ARG("%p", &handle->finished_cond_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&handle->finished_cond_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_lock");

        restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    /* Unlock the finished_cond_mtx in cleanup handler if cancelled here */
    pthread_cleanup_push(unlock_finished_cond_mtx, handle);

    /* Restore cancelstate while waiting for condition variable
     * to allow cancellation in this case. But set cancellation type to DEFERRED
     * in order to make sure we cancel during pthread_cond_wait, which should guarantee
     * that the finished_cond_mtx is locked during the cleanup handler. */
    set_canceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, &oldtype);
    restore_cancelstate(oldstate);

    while (!(handle->finished)) {
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(3 FUNC(pthread_cond_wait) ARG("%p", &handle->finished_cond) ARG("%p", &handle->finished_cond_mtx));
        if ((rc = pthread_cond_wait(&handle->finished_cond, &handle->finished_cond_mtx)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_cond_wait");
            break;
        }
    }

    disable_cancellations(&oldstate);
    restore_canceltype(oldtype);

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &handle->finished_cond_mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&handle->finished_cond_mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
    }

    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);

    restore_cancelstate(oldstate);

    /* This should be only because of pthread_cond_wait failing, not pthread_mutex_unlock */
    if (rc != 0) {
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", 0));
    return 0;
}

int threadpool_acquire_handle(threadpool_handle_t thandle)
{
    struct threadpool_handle *handle;
    int oldstate;
    int rc;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", thandle));
    disable_cancellations(&oldstate);

    handle = (struct threadpool_handle *)thandle;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_lock) ARG("%p", &handle->mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&handle->mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_lock");

        restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    /* Check for overflow */
    if (handle->refcount >= UINT64T_MAX) {
        ASYNCIO_ERROR("handle refcount overflow\n");

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &handle->mtx));
        if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&handle->mtx)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
        }

        restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", -1));
        return -1;
    }

    ++(handle->refcount);

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &handle->mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&handle->mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
    }

    restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(RET("%d", 0));
    return 0;
}

void threadpool_release_handle(threadpool_handle_t thandle)
{
    struct threadpool_handle *handle;
    int oldstate;
    int rc;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_ENTER(1 ARG("%p", thandle));
    disable_cancellations(&oldstate);

    handle = (struct threadpool_handle *)thandle;

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_lock) ARG("%p", &handle->mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&handle->mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_lock");
        restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
        return;
    }

    /* Check for underflow */
    if (handle->refcount == 0) {
        ASYNCIO_ERROR("Handle refcount already 0 before release.\n");

        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &handle->mtx));
        if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&handle->mtx)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
        }

        restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
        return;
    }

    --(handle->refcount);

    if (handle->refcount == 0) {
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &handle->mtx));
        if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&handle->mtx)) != 0) {
            errno = rc;
            ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
        }

        cleanup_threadpool_handle(handle);

        safe_free(handle);

        restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
        ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
        return;
    }

    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_CALL(2 FUNC(pthread_mutex_unlock) ARG("%p", &handle->mtx));
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&handle->mtx)) != 0) {
        errno = rc;
        ASYNCIO_SYSERROR("pthread_mutex_unlock");
    }

    restore_cancelstate(oldstate);
    ASYNCIO_DEBUG_RETURN(VOIDRET);
}
```

Comment: Just want to say, I like the way you code. Looks very clean. Programming in a language like C, it's very easy to write spaghetti code or extremely complicated macro excuses for functions. Well done

Answer (score 2):

After some testing with Valgrind, I discovered a few memory leaks in the threadpool module.

To explain, the threadpool handles are reference counted using the `refcount` field in the struct. When the refcount reaches 0, the structure is freed (`threadpool_release_handle` deals with decrementing the refcount and freeing when 0). The `threadpool_dispatch` function sets the initial refcount of the returned handle to 2, one for the caller, and one for the worker/contractor threads.

But there is a case where references are not decremented properly and the handle refcount remains at 1 even after caller has called `threadpool_release_handle` and the task has completed/cancelled. This happens if the user calls `threadpool_cancel` while the handle is still in the workers/contractors queue. The `threadpool_cancel` function takes it out of the queue, but I forgot to also call `threadpool_release_handle` to release the worker's reference to handle.

I fixed this issue in the latest version of the source published in GitHub.

There is another memory leak I discovered which is that `pthread_create` allocates some internal memory which remains until someone calls `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach`. But there are cases where the thread terminates and `pthread_detach` is not called. I have not yet figured out how to fix this, so this issue is still present but I will be working to find a fix.